# Central and local git repository with WAMP on local network

Tags: php, git, repository, localhost, wamp

Is it possible to setup central git repository for all projects under webroot with WAMP installed?

In other words, each project under webroot should be git-managed at a central pc where other developers can access the same and commit to that local centeral repository instead of some online location ?

I don't know much about network stuff or how other users will be able to access it.

This would create a nice work-flow for the developers ofcourse.

**What I have done so far:**

- Created a folder somewhere on my hard drive named **repo**
- Shared above folder with all permissions with everyone
- git initialized it or other projects inside it
- Added above folder to apache vhosts file with alias
- Now I can access above folder with `http://repo.com/`
- Made apace listen to my network IP instead of `localhost` from httpd.conf eg `Listen 192.168.1.4:80`

But other users can't access it when they go to `http://repo.com/`.

Does anyone know how to setup it so that other users can also access this from my pc and use git as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a tool to manage hosted git. For example, in the past I used gitosis, but there is other alternatives like gitolite:

1. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gitosis
2. https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite

I think you can't install gitosis on Windows, so you need a Linux machine (I have experience running gitosis with Ubuntu with no problems). If you google you can find several tutorials explaining how to run gitosis under Ubuntu, for example:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Git
- http://www.serverubuntu.it/git-gitosis-ubuntu

I remember it was very easy, but you need some Linux experience. Good luck!